# Commonsware Drag Drop shrinks row height permanently

Tags: android, commonsware-cwac

I did get the drag and drop working and the TouchListView class works great. However in my case I have rows of various height due to my adapter which contains an EditText that can have multiple lines. Therefore after I drop, all my rows convert to the tlv:normal_height which in my case is 74dip. This causes many rows to cut off all my text in the EditTexts. I tried re initializing  my adapter (mylistview.setAdapter= myadapter),  setting the ListView to GONE then VISIBLE and invalidateViews() but nothing seems to reset the ListView back to before I dragged, short of leaving the activity and coming back. What can be done here? -Thx

```
tlv:normal_height="74dip"
tlv:expanded_height="128dip"
```

Answer (score 0):

There's little question that the original AOSP code was designed for uniform row heights, and the whole `expanded_height` construct was there to provide space for the user to visualize where the drop would occur.

One starting point would probably be to create a `TouchListAdapter` mixin interface (akin to `SpinnerAdapter`) where the `normal_height` and `expanded_height` would be retrieved dynamically from the adapter based on `position` as opposed to being fixed values declared in the layout. Whether that alone would be sufficient or more work would need to be done, I can't say.

If you come up with a solution, patches are welcome. Otherwise, I'll probably take a look at this sometime, but not very soon.

My apologies for not having a near-term silver bullet.

Comment: I see, thanks. I will see if I can edit the TouchListView class a bit and see if I can set the row heights dynamically based on the ListView item's height. I assume I can access the ListView' adapter from the TouchListView class - so can you point me to the right location in the code?

Comment: @Mike: Use `getAdapter()` to get the adapter.

Answer (score 0):

I edited the unExpandViews() method - called getAdapter() and for every item in my adapter set the height to 0 and then all the rows were set back to original. I also bypassed the delete part of the method since it did not apply to me.

```
private void unExpandViews(boolean deletion) {

            int height_saved = 0;

            CheckBoxifiedTextListAdapter cbla = (CheckBoxifiedTextListAdapter)getAdapter();

            for (int i = 0;i < cbla.getCount(); i++) 
            {
                    //View v = getChildAt(i);

                    View v = cbla.getView(i, null, null);

                    //if (v == null) 
                    //{      
                           /*
                            if (deletion) 
                            {
                                    // HACK force update of mItemCount
                                    int position = getFirstVisiblePosition();
                                    int y = getChildAt(0).getTop();
                                    setAdapter(getAdapter());
                                    setSelectionFromTop(position, y);
                                    // end hack
                            }
                            layoutChildren(); // force children to be recreated where needed
                            v = getChildAt(i);

                            if (v == null) 
                            {
                                    break;
                            }
                            height_saved = v.getHeight();
                            */
                    //}
                    //else

                    //height_saved = v.getHeight();

                    if (isDraggableRow(v)) 
                    {
                        ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = v.getLayoutParams();
                        params.height = 0;
                        v.setLayoutParams(params);
                        v.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    }
            }
    }
```